# Trusted Web Activity: Navigating back to the Main Activity reveals the website URL during the period of transition

Tags: android, trusted-web-activity

The website I am redirecting to takes a few seconds to load due to runtime activities. During the load, if I try navigating back to the main activity (on pressing the back button on my android phone), the URL of the website is revealed (for a brief moment) during the transition phase from the website to the app. This shouldn't be the case as it would defeat the purpose of TWA and hiding of the URL bar. How do I avoid this issue?

Note: The URL bar is hidden rest of the time, meaning the application and the website has established a connection and the TWA is working as it is supposed to.

Comment: If I understood correctly, both the domain opened initially and the second domain are validated? Would you be able to post a video on what's happening? That could be helpful.

Comment: There is just one domain. I am able to redirect and the URL bar is being removed as expected. Just that when I hit the back button of my android phone and go back to the main activity the url bar is visible for a fraction of second. I'll try to make a video.

Comment: Got it. No need for the video. This sounds like a bug. Can you file an issue at https://bugs.chromium.org/?

Comment: Alright. I will file an issue. Thanks for your help on this. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand much about it, the little I understand would be to establish a connection between the website and the Android application in order to use 'digital asset links' linking the website to the application and the application to the website as well. I'm sorry if I didn't understand you correctly and I'm sorry for the English too.